# Is there a proverb that means "to solve two problems at once"?

Tags: translation, proverbs

In my language, we have a proverb that means "to solve two problems with only one solution". It would be literally translated as:

> I've killed two bunnies with only one hit

How would this be said in English? Is there a proverb with such a meaning?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the German expression for this translates as "to smash two flies with one flap".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [(killing) two birds with one stone](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kill+two+birds+with+one+stone).

Apparently, it's a [very old idea](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_origin_of_%27to_kill_two_birds_with_one_stone%27).

Though, as comedian Demetri Martin observes:

> When in history has there ever been a surplus of birds and a shortage of stones?

Answer (score 5):

English has a similar phrase:

> I killed two birds with one stone